# SP2010, Odata, anonymous access

Tags: wcf, odata, json

Is anonymous access to listdata.svc possible?  I'm trying to just simply get list items and display them using json but I either get asked to login or a 401 unauthorized.  It's a claims based site with NTLM authentication and anonymous access enabled.  Anonymous access to the list itself works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC listdata.svc does not allow anonymous access even if anonymous access is enabled for the site.

Could you try using the Client Object Model instead of going throught the services directly?

Comment: I figured as much.  Seems like the Client Object Model is going to be my only option.  Not anywhere near as convenient unfortunately.  Such is life in the Sharepoint world -- nothing is ever easy, and if it's easy it's not useful :)

Comment: The Client Object Model doesn't work with anonymous access either, at least in JavaScript.

Comment: The JSCOM only works in an authenticated manner and in the context of the SharePoint site that the user is currently browsing. So, yes, it is authenicated access only.

The .NET managed client object model should work in an anonymous manner :)